# Speed up creating a graph from 2.92M data points

Tags: python, ruby, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx

I have 2.92M data points in a 3.0GB CSV file and I need to loop through it twice to create a graph which I want to load into NetworkX. At the current rate it will take me days to generate this graph. How can I speed this up?

```
similarity = 8

graph = {}
topic_pages = {}

CSV.foreach("topic_page_node_and_edge.csv") do |row|
                topic_pages[row[0]] = row[1..-1]
end

CSV.open("generate_graph.csv", "wb") do |csv|
        i = 0
        topic_pages.each do |row|
                i+=1
                row = row.flatten
                topic_pages_attributes = row[1..-1]
                graph[row[0]] = []
                topic_pages.to_a[i..-1].each do |row2|
                        row2 = row2.flatten
                        topic_pages_attributes2 = row2[1..-1]
                        num_matching_attributes = (topic_pages_attributes2 & topic_pages_attributes).count
                        if num_matching_attributes >= similarity or num_matching_attributes == topic_pages_attributes2.count or num_matching_attributes == topic_pages_attributes.count
                                graph[row[0]].push(row2[0])
                        end
                end
                csv << [row[0], graph[row[0]]].flatten
        end
end
```

Comment: By showing us your code?

Comment: How much RAM do you have available on that machine? You're trying to hold 2.92M data points in memory, and each point *isn't* taking a single byte.

Comment: Do you really need to graph all 3e6 points? A decent random sample should give you a good enough graph for eyeballs.

Comment: By a brief look I see fundamental flaw in an inner loop with repeated conversion of huge 3 GB hash `topic_pages` to an array yet followed by its slicing. Need to be refactored to avoid such expensive code.

Comment: @muistooshort i need to create the entire graph because i'm needing to find cliques in it.

Comment: @DavidUnric thanks. i'll refactor the code that but i don't think it will help as much. It takes 5 minutes to go through the one pass of the 3M data points. At this rate it is going to take ~ 5 min * 2.9M

Comment: Okay, you're talking "Graph Theory" graph, not "pretty pictures" graph. I should have paid more attention to the names in the code and the question tags, sorry.

Comment: Can you at least slop the data into a database, do any prep work you need inside the database, and then dump a CSV from there? 3e6 rows is nothing to a decent database.

Comment: Since you are afraid for it to takes days, I assume preprocessing is out of the question since that would also take days?

Comment: Also not sure if this was intentional but is your graph supposed to only be one way?

Comment: @RichardFung it is an undirected graph.

Comment: Well the way you have it written its only one way no? Because for each row[i] it wont have a reference to any row[j] st j<i

Comment: @KaranVerma *It takes 5 minutes to go through the one pass of the 3M data points* Avoid re-creation of that huge Hash and you'll see it'll take a fragment of that 5 minutes. When the loop is processed 3 million times, it'd have a several impact on total time.

Answer (score 2):

1. **benchmark**. For example using cProfile, which comes with Python. It's easy to have some costly inefficiencies in your code, and they can easily come at a 10x performance cost in intensive applications.

   Pretty code such as

   ```
   (topic_pages_attributes2 & topic_pages_attributes).count
   ```

   *may* turn out to be a major factor in your runtime, that can easily be reduced by using more traditional code.
2. Use a more efficient language. For example in [benchmarksgame.alioth](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=python3&lang2=gcc&data=u32), on a number of intensive problems, the *fastest* Python 3 program is in median 63x slower than the fastest C program (Ruby is at 67x, JRuby at 33x). Yes, the performance gap *can* be big, even with well-optimized Python code. But if you didn't optimize your code, it may be even bigger; and you may be able to get a 100x-1000x speedup by using a more efficient language and carefully optimizing your code.
3. Consider more clever formulations of your problem. For example, instead of iterating over each node, iterate over each *edge* once. In your case, that would probably mean building an inverted index, topic -> pages. This is very similar to the way text search engines work, and a popular way to compute such operations on clusters: the individual topics can be split on separate nodes. This approach benefits from the *sparsity* in your data.
   This can take down the runtime of your algorithm drastically.

   You have about 3 Mio documents. Judging from your total data size, they probably have less than 100 topics on average? Your pairwise comparison approach needs 3mio^2 comparisons, that is what hurts you. If the more popular topics are used on only 30.000 documents each, you may get away with computing only 30k^2 * number of topics. Assuming you have 100 of such very popular topics (rare topics don't matter much), this would be a 100x speedup.
4. Simplify your problem. For example, *first* merge all documents that have *exactly* the same topics by sorting. To make this more effective, also eliminate all topics that occur exactly once. But probably there are only some 10.000-100.000 different *sets* of documents. This step can be easily solved using sorting, and will make your problem some 900-90000 times easier (assuming above value range).

Some of these numbers may be too optimistic - for example, IO was not taken into account at all, and if your problem is I/O bound, using C/Java may not help much. There may be some highly popular topics that can hurt with the approaches discussed in C. For D) you need O(n log n) time for sorting your data; but there are very good implementations for this available. But it definitely is a simplification that you should do. These documents will also form fully connected cliques in your final data, which likely hurt other analyses as well.

Answer (score 0):

The most amount of time is spent in loading data from disk i belive. Parallelize reading data into multiple threads / processes and then create graph.

Also you could probably create subset graphs in different machines and combine them later.

Comment: If disk I/O is indeed the bottleneck here, I can't see how creating multiple threads to read from the disk will help.

Comment: @Deepank Even if I read the graph in memory. I need to processes attributes 2.92M other nodes to figure if an edge exists. I bench marked that and it takes about 4-5 minutes. 

Please elaborate how I can reduce the problem into subproblems and combine them later.